# How to reload data in a table made in xib

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, reloaddata

[myTable reloadData] isn't working nor is [myTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

I previously subclassed UITableViewController, where both these functions worked.  I then changed my class to subclass UIViewController with delegates so I can use a xib.  Since then these functions stopped working.

I have it set up so that reloadData is triggered by a button click.  Running the debugger many times showed that the table methods aren't even being triggered by reloadData, though the table loads fine to begin with (before clicking the button).  Delegate source and delegate are set to File's Owner, so that's all fine.

Thank you so much.

Comment: found this result:  [(UITableView*)self.view reloadData]; but it causes a crash after couple loads

Comment: This is because your view is no longer a UITableView as you are no longer subclassing UITableViewController. I can expand my answer below to explain this if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have an outlet set to myTable. That would explain why datasource and delegate work, but not calls to reload data.

Assuming this is the issue you need the following in your @interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;
```

and an instance variable `UITableView *myTable`. Then you need `@synthesize myTable;` in your implementation.

Then you need to use interface builder to assign your table view to this outlet by dragging from the myTable entry in File's Owner > Connections tab to your table view in the layout.

Assuming this was the problem , you will now be able to call methods such as reloadData on your table view.

Comment: Hi Mason, thanks for your answer. That doesn't seem to affect things.  I did have everything connected in IB already, without using retain on myTable (the sample code I've seen didn't use retain or synthesize), but I put all that in now for a try.  Unfortunately still responds the same - the code hits [myTable reloadData] but this doesn't call the table functions, basically nothing happens: it doesn't enter the table code block.

Comment: Interesting. Can you do NSLog(@"%@", myTable) and check that it's not nil?

Comment: Yup, you're right - it's null.  Good thinking to try that. How should I handle that? So far I've got a retain, synthesize, IBOutlet UITableView on mytable.  My interface declaration is: @interface TableView : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>        .  My tableview is connected in IB to File's Owner as Datasourse, Delegate, and myTable.  So I'm sure what I should be tinkering with. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: My guess is that the xib isn't being used, but File's Owner identity is associated with my class - TableView. So no go there.

Comment: Sounds frustrating! You can test if the XIB is being used by placing (for instance) a big button in it somewhere and seeing if that renders on screen when you run the app. If you want to upload the classes or project somewhere I can take a look.

Comment: I'll try and see what adding a button does.  I can also upload the project to something like DropBox for you to look at.  I'm not at home right now till much later, so I can leave you a note here when it's available or if I've made any breakthroughs.  Really appreciate your help. So nice of you. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, I know how annoying this stuff can be!

Comment: Hi Mason, I sent a DropBox link to the email on the website (thetuttroom.com) in your account.  Let me know if that'll get to you and you managed to get it alright.  I just set up the account so I'm not sure if it worked.  Very nice work on your site by the way.  You're very talented.  I also included a README file with my email, hope there's enough information there to go on.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, didn't get a DropBox link? Could you zip the project and send to micknaso@hotmail.com?

Comment: It's not possible to send executables over email (gmail at least).  I tried sending a dropbox invitation to your hotmail.  Let me know if it doesn't work again - I'll think of something else.  Cheers.

Comment: Hi, got the link fine this time. Weird it didn't make it through first time round. Your problem was that you were editing the wrong XIB! You have MainWindow.XIB and PickerView.XIB, and you were editing PickerView whereas the actual table view that was being used was in MainWindow, so you had the myTable outlet set in PickerView but not in MainWindow, hence the confusion. It's easy to get confused in Interface Builder! I've put the fixed files back in DropBox for you.

Comment: Oh My God.  What an embarrassing oversight.  I'm sorry to have bothered you with such a simple thing.  I'm also embarrassed I fooled around with it for a couple days myself. Since I'm relatively new to Objective-c I figured, like the Main class, that this MainWindow.xib was some default thing that I shouldn't mess with or look at ('cause I didn't start the project).  Such a silly mistake.  Again thank you so much, and thanks for all your time and help!

Comment: No worries! I know how confusing Interface Builder is when you first start out. Some people avoid using it at all for that very reason. Glad to have been of help!